# Cannot list repository webhooks using personal access token in private repo

Tags: github, github-api

I'm working on two repos, one is private and one is public. In the public repo, I can create a personal access token with repo/webhooks admin permissions and I can run the following command:

```
curl -si https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{repo}/hooks -H "Authorization: token {token}"
```

and I get back `[]`, an empty list because there's no webhooks.

In the private repo, if I create a personal access token, even with *all* permissions, I always get:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/webhooks/repos#list-repository-webhooks"
}
```

What's going on here? Is it possible that programmatic access to webhooks is somehow disabled by the repo owner or something?

I can see other resources of the private repo with the token though, like `/repos/{user}/{repo}/branches`. It is specifically `/hooks` that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. In order to access webhooks via the github API the token needs to be bound to an account with a role that has the `Manage Webhooks` permissions.

On my personal repo, I had the `admin` role which has that permission by default, on the private repo I had the `write` role which does not.